# How to edit TeXShop typeset program list

Tags: texshop

I never typeset with Metapost, ConTeX or Plain TeX. Is it possible to remove them from the list of programs that appear in the popup menu in TeXShop? I know I can add scripts or engines by placing files in the `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines` but how can one remove them?

Comment: Quit the application. Create a directory `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines.disabled`, for example, and move the relevant engines there. (You could just delete them but I'd move them as it is easier to track things and find them should you need them.) Then restart the application.

Comment: @cfr There's already an Inactive folder inside the Engines folder. Just drag the one's you don't want into the Inactive folder and restart TeXShop.

Comment: @AlanMunn I couldn't remember the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Engines folder inside `~/Library/TeXShop` contains an `Inactive` folder.  You can move any engine files you don't need into that folder. When you restart TeXShop the menu will change to show just the remaining active engines.

Comment: Dear Alan: Thanks but this was the first thing I did before posting the question, I moved all the not-used engines to Inactive but the button keep displaying Metapost, ConTeXt, etc... I just installed the last update of TeXShop. I search for other locations in my system for .engine files (finder > system files are displayed) but there were none besides the Inactive folder. I will try to re-install TeXShop to see if the behavior changes.

Comment: Even after after deleting the ~/Library/TeXShop folder, the button still displays Metapost and ConTeXt.

Comment: I've never really tried to remove everything. I assume then that PlainTeX, LaTeX, BibTeX, MakeIndex, Metapost and ConTeXt are built into the code and cannot be removed.  But how often do you actually use the menu anyway?  I just use Command-T to typeset, Command-B to Bibtex  and use  `% !TEX TS-program = ` directives in the source file if I need to switch from my default engine.

Comment: If you delete the folder, it will be recreated next time you launch the application, won't it? That's how it used to work, at least.